# Javascript - reformatting a dictionary to an array of dictionaries

Tags: javascript

I have the list of people and the frequency number in a dicitonary below, I am trying to format it as

```
var frequency_list = [{"text":"Jay Sekulow","size":1},{"text":"Jeff Mason","size":1},.....]
```

Above is the format the D3.js requires for one of the charts:

The original list:

```
 {    'Jay Sekulow': 1,
             'Jeff Mason': 1,
             'John Bolton': 2,
             'John Dowd': 1,
             'Jonathan Oatis': 3,
             'Michael Cohen': 2,
             'Michael Dreeben': 1,
             'Mike Pence': 2,
             'Patricia Zengerle': 1,
             'Paul Manafort': 2,
             'Rod Rosenstein': 1,
             'Ronald Reagan': 1,
             'Rudy Giuliani': 2,
             'Sarah N. Lynch': 1,
             'Sergei Skripal': 2, }
```

How would I go about that in javascript?I tried the below code but it's giving me a wrong format:

```
    var freq_list = [];
    Object.keys(person).forEach(function(key) {
      var str = "{ \"text\": \""+ key + "\", \"size\": \"" + person[key] +"\"}";
       freq_list.push(str);
    });
console.log(freq_list)
```

result:

```
["{ \"text\": \"Jay Sekulow\", \"size\": \"1\"}","{ \"text\": \"Jeff Mason\", \"size\": \"1\"},......]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
    'Jay Sekulow': 1,
    'Jeff Mason': 1,
    'John Bolton': 2,
    'John Dowd': 1,
    'Jonathan Oatis': 3,
    'Michael Cohen': 2,
    'Michael Dreeben': 1,
    'Mike Pence': 2,
    'Patricia Zengerle': 1,
    'Paul Manafort': 2,
    'Rod Rosenstein': 1,
    'Ronald Reagan': 1,
    'Rudy Giuliani': 2,
    'Sarah N. Lynch': 1,
    'Sergei Skripal': 2,
};

var finalArray = Object.keys(data).map(val => {
    return {
        "text": val,
        "size": data[val]
    }
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the new `Object.entries` function -- or if you're using an older version of javascript to support older browsers, consider `Object.keys`

```
const original = {
  'Jay Sekulow': 1,
  'Jeff Mason': 1,
  'John Bolton': 2,
  'John Dowd': 1,
  'Jonathan Oatis': 3,
  'Michael Cohen': 2,
  'Michael Dreeben': 1,
  'Mike Pence': 2,
  'Patricia Zengerle': 1,
  'Paul Manafort': 2,
  'Rod Rosenstein': 1,
  'Ronald Reagan': 1,
  'Rudy Giuliani': 2,
  'Sarah N. Lynch': 1,
  'Sergei Skripal': 2
}

function formatInfo(info) {
  return Object.entries(info).map(([text, size]) => ({text, size}))
}

const formatted = formatInfo(original)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code snippet. first parse your input and then `reduce` will help you out. you can also use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)'s `groupBy` method too

```js
const frequency_list = '[{"text":"Jay Sekulow","size":1},{"text": "Jeff Mason","size":1}]';

const a = JSON.parse(frequency_list);

const result = a.reduce((solution, item) => { 
  solution[item.text]= item.size; return solution
}, {});

console.log(result);
```